# Prevent the creation of events with conflicting times with FullCalendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fullcalendar

I'm trying to disable dayclick from functioning when there is already an event at the time. Is this possible? I've seen functions that stop people dragging one event to a conflicting time, but nothing that acts before creation.

Thanks

Comment: you might be able play with [eventRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/)?  As it is rendering, trigger some function that prevents it being clickable if there is already an event

Comment: Can you attach a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sorted it with click events function

```
function checkOverlap(event) {  

    var start = new Date(event);
    var end = new Date(event.end);

    var overlap = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(ev) {
        if( ev == event) {
            return false;
        }
        var estart = new Date(ev.start);
        var eend = new Date(ev.end);

        return (Math.round(estart) == Math.round(start));
    });

    if (overlap.length){  
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }               
}
```

This is mostly possible because my app only allows users to make appointments for 1 hour and always on the hour. If you have a more flexible model where you can have variable length and starting time of the appointments, you will have to fiddle with the following line:

```
return (Math.round(estart) == Math.round(start));
```